# Weird (colorless) texture rendering in THREE.js under Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, three.js

Trying to render GLB file with THREE.js on Node.js but get wrong result.
Everything is running under Debian on WSL2 with mesa drivers installed (as instructed by headless-gl package description).
The app runs with `xvfb-run -s "-ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24" node --trace-warnings -r esm app.js` command.

I using `JSDOM, canvas, node-canvas-webgl, xhr2` packages to emulate browser behavior to make THREE and GLTFLoader code running.

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO1lq.jpg) - [what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miqDj.png)

I also creating panorama with `CubemapToEquirectangular` but even without this package rendering works incorrect.

[result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSDG4.jpg) - [result in node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJL2B.jpg)

This initial code helps me run everything I need.

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const { window } = (new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>'));
global.window = window;
global.self = window;

global.document = window.document;

global.navigator = window.navigator;

global.File = window.File;
global.FileReader = window.FileReader;
global.Blob = window.Blob;

const createObjectURL = async object => {
  if (object instanceof Blob) {
    const convert = new Promise(resolve => {
      const a = new FileReader();
      a.onload = function(e) { resolve(e.target.result); };
      a.readAsDataURL(object);
    });
    return await convert;
  } else return typeof object === typeof '' ? object : '';
};

global.URL = window.URL;
global.URL.createObjectURL = createObjectURL;
global.URL.revokeObjectURL = url => null;

global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');

global.atob = require('atob');

const nodeCanvas = require('canvas');

global.ImageData = nodeCanvas.ImageData;
global.Image = nodeCanvas.Image;

global.Image.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture) {
  this['on' + type] = listener.bind(this);
};
global.Image.prototype.removeEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture) {
  this['on' + type] = null;
};

global.document.createElementNS = (uri, type) => {
  if (type === 'img') {
    const image = new global.Image();
    return image;
  }
  return window.document.createElementNS(uri, type);
};

global.TextDecoder = require('util').TextDecoder;
```

I also use `createCanvas` from `node-canvas-webgl` to create canvas for renderer

```
const { createCanvas } = require('node-canvas-webgl/lib');

const canvas = createCanvas(512, 512);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
```

BTW `node-canvas-webgl/lib/canvas.js` is modified on line `108` to make it work correct

```
- if(pixels._image) pixels = pixels._image;
+ if(pixels && pixels._image) pixels = pixels._image;
```

The rest of the code is pretty much the same as in every THREE examples.

I also have to mention that Duck.glb renders correct, but no other big model I have tried.

[duck is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UN2Y.jpg)

Did someone faced this problem and is there any solution?

Comment: Does `node-canvas-webgl` support what you are trying to do?

Comment: don't know if supports, but from package description it seems that it should